# Tem como eu fazer um ponteiro de char apontar para cada posição de um vetor de char na linguagem C?

Tags: c

ex: suponhamos uma string chamada "Gustavo". Como eu faço um ponteiro apontar pra cada posição da string e ir aplicando a seguinte regra.

1. Se o ponteiro encontrar a vogal A, o conteúdo desse ponteiro deve receber "AUAU"
2. Se o ponteiro encontrar a vogal U, o conteúdo desse ponteiro deve receber "AUAUAUAUAU"

ficando no final o conteúdo do ponteiro assim: GAUAUAUAUAUstAUAUvo

OBS: Não quero modificar a string original e sim utilizar ela como base para 
 poder aplicar as regras acima, armazenando-as no conteúdo do meu ponteiro.

Comment: Acredito que você não pode apontar para string resultante com esse ponteiro sem utilizar uma variável auxiliar, a não ser que você estivesse alterando a própria string que está sendo verificada. Mas seria bom você mostrar o que já tentou.

Comment: Para você fazer tal substituição terá que copiar para a string resultante ou cada caractere lido  que não necessite ser substituído ou  a cadeia de caracteres substituta. Você terá que  alocar memória para a string resultante. O que pode fazer é realocar a cada inclusão de caractere(s) na string.

Comment: https://ideone.com/r4V9ro